# UFW or iptables need help!

Tags: server, iptables, ufw

I have been using UFW for a long time. IT is great.
There is one problem.
I want to block all IPs (all countries) and just except incoming connections from the orange operator from Poland.

Orange IP is: 83.6.x.x and 83.9.x.x (allowed)
all other IPs (block)
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately this isn’t too difficult:

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 83.6.0.0/16 to 83.6.255.255 port 80
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 83.9.0.0/16 to 83.9.255.255 port 80
```

Be sure to change the `port` value to the one you actually want, and the same with `tcp`.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Matigo. 
For me it works the best!


> ufw allow proto tcp from 83.6.0.0/16 to 192.168.1.0/24 port 80 
> ufw allow proto tcp from 83.9.0.0/16 to 192.168.1.0/24 port 80



were '192.168.1.0' is my LAN network